# "Root composer.json requires ocramius/package-versions..." but there is no such requirement in my composer.json

Tags: symfony, composer-php

In a Symfony 4 project, I'm getting problems after a composer selfupdate to 2.1 (from 1.x). One of the error messages when hitting

```
composer update nothing
```

is:

> Root composer.json requires ocramius/package-versions == 1.3.0.0 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.3.0].

What is really strange in my opinion is that my composer.json does not contain any references to "ocramius/package-versions" and somehow I don't manage to trace where it comes from. Even stranger: When I try

```
composer show ocramius/package-versions --tree
```

I get

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Package ocramius/package-versions not found

The only references to "ocramius/package-versions" in my project come from

1. composer.lock
2. vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/composer.json
3. vendor/composer/installed.json

It seems it is stuck in the composer.lock, but I dont want to run a real composer update on the whole project because of side effects. Any ideas what I could do?

EDIT:
After getting poked into the direction of `composer why` I managed to find out why ocramius/package-versions is included at all, but still 1.3.0:

```
 $ composer why ocramius/package-versions
composer/package-versions-deprecated  1.11.99.2  replaces  ocramius/package-versions (1.11.99)       
ocramius/package-versions             2.3.0      replaces  composer/package-versions-deprecated (*)

$ composer why composer/package-versions-deprecated
composer/package-versions-deprecated  1.11.99.2  replaces  ocramius/package-versions (1.11.99)          
doctrine/migrations                   3.2.0      requires  composer/package-versions-deprecated (^1.8)  
doctrine/orm                          2.7.5      requires  composer/package-versions-deprecated (^1.8)  
symfony/proxy-manager-bridge          v4.4.25    requires  composer/package-versions-deprecated (^1.8)
```

Ok, so I finally found why the packages is included. But why the wrong version?
Then the scales fell from my eyes: Why not just update it instead of trying to find out why this version is chosen...???
A simple

```
composer update ocramius/package-versions
```

did the trick. D'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the [packagist page of that package](https://packagist.org/packages/ocramius/package-versions#1.3.0), v1.3.0 is not compatible with Composer v2, as it requires `composer-plugin-api: ^1.0.0`. You need to update that package if you want to use Composer v2.

If you want to check which package requires this one, you can use `composer why`